# Applying a patch to files with spaces in names

Tags: cygwin, diff, patch

Here's an output of `diff -u "temp temp/docs 1.txt" "temp temp/docs 2.txt"`:

```
--- temp temp/docs 1.txt    Mon Apr  7 16:15:08 2014
+++ temp temp/docs 2.txt    Mon Apr  7 16:18:45 2014
@@ -2,6 +2,6 @@
 22
 333
 4444
-555555
+55555
 666666
 7777777
```

However, feeding this diff to `patch -u` fails with following message:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- temp temp/docs 1.txt       Mon Apr  7 16:15:08 2014
|+++ temp temp/docs 2.txt       Mon Apr  7 16:18:45 2014
--------------------------
```

Apparently, the spaces are the problem; is there a way to make `patch` to work on files with spaces in names?

Comment: As a side note, if you're using git, why aren't you using `git diff` and `git apply`?

Comment: @Cupcake Because I am not using git?.. I have just a Cygwin installation with `diff` and `patch`.

Comment: Your question is tagged with [tag:git] :P I'll fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, GNU patch doesn't support this.  Here's the official statement: http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unusual-File-Names.html#Unusual%20File%20Names

Comment: White space is an "unusual character". Indeed, why would anyone want a space in a file name? Surely a minus or an underscores is a better choice. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Gnu patch 2.6.1 (linux) seems to obey at least 1 space (not tried with more) if the filename is separated from the date with tab.

YYMV

Comment: Worked for me with two spaces in the path.  Also seems like `git diff` will auto-add the tab character for you if the path has a space.

Comment: Every quilt refresh needs to do this for files/paths with spaces modified by the patch files on the series file. This is very annoying, and i wish there was a way to tell quilt refresh to just add a tab on every header filename instead of failing on a 'pop' (it applies fine).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when trying to establish conventions how to do manual version control with diff and patch.

I found out that GNU "diff" creates quoted path names in the patch headers if they contain spaces, while BusyBox "diff" doesn't.

Neither GNU nor BusyBox "patch" accepts quoted path names.

If the problem is just embedded spaces within filenames, it can therefore be avoided by using "busybox patch" rather than GNU "patch".

Another solution is to postprocess the output of GNU "diff" before feeding it into "patch":

```
sed 's,^\([-+]\{3\} \)"\([^"]*\)",\1\2,' $PATCHFILE | patch -p1
```

This works whether $PATCHFILE was created with GNU or busybox diff, but will only work with unified diff format.

Unfortunately, it turns out that leading or trailing spaces in filenames cannot be preserved with this method, as "patch" will skip them when parsing the path names from the patch instructions.

The approach will neither work if the filename starts with a literal double quote - but then, who uses such file names?

Most of the time, however, the above approach works just fine.

Finally a note of other approaches I have also tried but which did *not* work:

First I tried to replace the quotation of the whole path names by individually quoted path name components. This failed because "patch" does not use double quotes as meta-characters at all. It considers them to be normal literal characters.

Then I tried to replace all spaces by "\040" like CVS does - but "patch" does not seem to accept octal-escapes either, and this failed too.